# Who has the responsibility to make altimeter corrections in cold temperatures?

Tags: air-traffic-control, altitude, altimeter, cold-weather

I work as air traffic controller in Asia and we refer to both ICAO and FAA regulations. As winter is coming, there is a debate on altitude correction (or altimeter correction?) for cold temperatures. Some insist that we (ATC) don't have the responsibility to make altitude correction, and the others insist that we have, when ATC performs radar vectoring. (We know that the pilots have responsibility when IAP.)

In related to this, ICAO DOC 8168 states (Vol 1, Chap 4 Altimeter correction):

> The pilot is responsible for these corrections, **except when under radar vectoring.** In that case, the radar controller issues clearances such that the prescribed obstacle clearance will exist at all times, taking the cold temperature correction into account.

So, I've tried to find references about this but failed.

Here're my questions.

1) Is there a document or manual for ATC about how to make altitude corrections when radar vectoring?

2) Why is there no altitude correction for hot temperatures that make for a steep angle of descent?

3) Should ATC-issued altitudes take into account temperature-induced altimeter error, or does should ATC issue the true altitude and leave the responsibility on the pilot for making the correction?

Comment: Hot temps aren’t really a problem since the plane will be flying at an altitude *above* what his altimeter reads. With low temps it can be *below* the reading risking terrain contact. I’m not sure what you’re asking in point 3. What barometer has an error?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking you management this, rather than getting advice from random strangers on the internet? As someone who sometimes flies in planes I hope that you controllers can work out what the correct process is without our help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have enough points to make a comment so I'll just leave this one...
http://code7700.com/altimeter_temperature_correction.htm

All throughout, it's
Pilot In Command...
Pilot In Command...
Pilot In Command...
Pilot In Command...

> 4.1.4 Air traffic control (ATC). If an aircraft is cleared by ATC to an altitude which the pilot-in-command finds unacceptable due to low temperature, then the pilot-in-command should request a higher altitude. If such a request is not received, ATC will consider that the clearance has been accepted and will be complied with. See Annex 2 and the PANS-ATM (Doc 4444), Chapter 6.

Answer (score 1):

I post couple of things i found. Basically this:

According to ICAO PANS OPS, minimum vectoring altitudes shall be corrected for temperature. The temperature correction shall be based on seasonal or annual minimum temperature records. In turn, ATC authorities are required, as per ICAO PANS ATM, 8.6.5.2, Note 2, “to provide the controller with minimum altitudes corrected for temperature effect”.

ICAO Doc 8168 - Aircraft Operations - Vol I, Part III, §1, Ch. 4] Note.— This chapter deals with altimeter corrections for pressure, temperature and, where appropriate, wind and terrain effects. The pilot is responsible for these corrections, except when under radar vectoring. In that case, the radar controller issues clearances such that the prescribed obstacle clearance will exist at all times, taking the cold temperature correction into account.